# appending json object in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

i've this vue object

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
            person:"",
            offset: 0,
            limit: 5
        },
        methods: {
            loadFirstSet: function() {
                getNewsJson(this.offset,this.limit,false);
            },
            loadMore: function() {
                this.offset += this.limit;
                getNewsJson(this.offset,this.limit,true);
            }
        }
    });
```

this is my axios request to get more data  from server

```
function getNewsJson(offset,limit,append){
        axios.get(baseApi + 'all_person/' + offset + '/' + limit)
        .then(function(response) {
            if(response.data.status == true) {
                if(response.data.result.length > 0) {
                    if(append) {
                        a = app.person;
                        b = a.push(response.data.result);
                        console.log(b);
                    } else {
                        app.person = response.data.result;
                        console.log(response.data.result);
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(function(response) {

        });
    }
```

I'm trying to append the new json object to already existing json object, to include the feature of **load more** but while doing it, it is not working properly, what can i do to append the json ?

Comment: Define "It is not working properly".

Comment: @DaveNewton on first go, console.log says "Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]" but when we click on Load more, console.log says "6", and clicking again says "7'

Comment: I don't see `app` defined anywhere? Also your `data.person` is a string, you can't push to a string.. it should be an array.

Comment: Also, `push` method returns the length of the array, not the array itself. So, `b` will always just be an integer.

Comment: @BrianGlaz app is defined as vue object, how can i convert data.person string to an array?
How would i know if array is pushed in my object?

Comment: instead of `person:""` do `person: []`; Then just `console.log(app.person)` instead of `console.log(b)`